# Create website which has usefull information like videos, third party API for live information on education

Tags: web

I want to create a website which consists of videos which will be uploaded by the admin and many useful information which all will be uploaded by an admin.
I have got the domain name, remote LAMP server.

I have gone through many tutorials and I tired creating using Drupal 8. Website was fine but while creating a new existing module the whole thing got crashed and I don't want to goback and recover it since it is a big mess.

So I want to try from first keeping it very simple.

Kindly guide me to achieve this. I will put all my effort to learn it.
Any help any documents which will help me to create will be greatly accepted.

I am beginner in C++, html. Can you guys let me know how can I achieve in creating a website.

Comment: Your question is like asking "how do I become a doctor" or "how do I build a car". Extremely broad and impossible to answer.

Comment: Hello Ceejayoz, How to become doctor or how to build car though it is very tough question. you can guide the learners by providing some fundamentals or basics.

Answer (score 0):

You can find your answer here on your own:

So there are various languages that are being used in the web that perform various purposed and hence you can choose what functionality do you need in your website and according to that you can write the code in that language.

Lets take a quick look at some of the most widely used languages of the web:

## 1: HTML

This is a Markup Language which can be used basically just for writing the content and displaying on your webpage. You can create too many pages and link them to form a website.

## 2: CSS

This language helps you design your webpage and thus makes your webpage look way too better. A site only written in html in not preferrable.

## 3: JavaScript

This language is a scripting language that helps you do various cool stuff like handling input events (like click, hover,etc), change the content of your webpage dynamically, bring popups , etc.

## 4: PHP

This scripting language is also being widely used as this lets you work with the forms and submit to a database. In fact, if you learn this language you can write the logic behind your own facebook and you can give it a face using HTML, CSS.

Once you are done learning all these languages, you can now learn some of the cool libraries like:

- Bootstrap (for css, js)
- Jquery (Javascript)

Comment: Hi Jason, I am planning to go with C++ as I already have knowledge on it and try using CPPCMS any thoughts from your end on it

Comment: I dont have any knowledge of how to make a website using c++ , sorry